# Dynamic pattern string for use in case statement

Tags: bash

I have the following option list

```
opts="-p,--plong,-q,--qlong"
```

I split the string into two other strings; one for short options, the other for long options like so.

```
ops="" opl=""
for kl in ${opts//,/ }; do
  if [[ "$kl" == --* ]]; then
    opl="${opl},${kl}"   # Short Options
  elif [[ "$kl" == -* ]]; then
    ops="${ops},${kl}"  # Long Options
  fi
done
opl="${opl:1}" ; ops="${ops:1}"
```

Which gives

```
ops: "-p,-q"
opl: "--plong,--qlong"
```

For the short options I want to construct an array consisting of the patterns

```
("-p+([[:print:]])" "-p" "-p=*" "-q+([[:print:]])" "-q" "-q=*")
```

And for the long options have

```
("--plong" "--plong=*" "--qlong" "--qlong=*")
```

Have started with the following scheme, which is not warking very well

```
echo "$ops" | tr ',' ' '  |
  xargs -I{} echo "-{}+([[:print:]])" "{}"

echo "$opl" | tr ',' ' '  |
  xargs -I{} echo "{}" "{}=*"
```

Comment: You seem still to be trying to solve the wrong problem

Answer (score -1):

I have solved this with

```
pary=()
for kl in ${ops//,/ }; do
  pary+=("$kl+([[:print:]])" "$kl")
done

printf '%s\n' "ary: ${ary[*]}"

qary=()
for kl in ${opl//,/ }; do
  qary+=("$kl" "${kl}=*")
done

printf '%s\n' "ary: ${ary[*]}"
```